# Need database with some country specific data like schools, medical centers etc

Tags: information-retrieval

Hi is there some database with official information about medical centers, schools, POI's and they'r geo coordinates for all countries in the world? It coul'd be not for free too, but I need the GEO coordinates as well, because I need to connect them to my products!

Thanks
Nik

Comment: You may want to consider the [Geographic Information Systems StackExchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) for this inquiry.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this really answers your question, but it is sure worth checking out. I have never used it, but I know people that use it for projects.

http://www.google.com/publicdata

You can explore data from a lot of countries, and all the data is nicely displayed. I think there also has to be an api so you can connect it to your application.

Comment: Well this are only statistics. I need to download this data and use it into my project. For example if I have some street then I would like to display all the stuff near by in 50 mi radios or something!

Comment: Ok sorry I thought it could be useful, guess not.

Comment: Hi, it is useful, but for stats only. I think the answer of my question is OpenStreetMap!